# Emacs auto updated to Python 3?

Tags: python-3.x, emacs, auto-update

Would emacs auto update from python 2.7 to 3? I tried to run some code today that I haven't ran in a while and now I'm getting tab errors all over the place, and it's python 3!

It's crazy right? Emacs wouldn't do that?

Answer (score 0):

It's probably because your system is set to python 3 by default now and it wasn't before. It really has nothing to do with a text editor. Although the package quickrun (if you're using it) could be set to use one version of python or the other.